# выборка данных с помощью LINQ или лямбда выражений

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, vb.net, лямбда-выражение

Всем привет , уважаемые гуру . Подскажите , как правильно получить значения из таблицы в базе данных ...
Делаю справку , которую можно редактировать в базе данных , пока знаний маловато ..
Есть следующая таблица :

```
Public Class AboutArticle
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Head As String
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property Right As Boolean // доступно подтверждённым  
    Public Property Themes As String // Описание Темы или Раздела 
End Class
```

пример метода в контроллере, возможно и тут что то поправите или посоветуете :

```
 Function About() As ActionResult
    Dim user1 = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.Login = User.Identity.Name)
    ViewData("User") = False
    If (user1 IsNot Nothing) Then
        ViewData("User") = user1.Right
    End If

    Dim articlesUserTrue = context.AboutArticles.ToList()

    Dim articlesUserFalse = From m In context.AboutArticles
                            Where (m.Right = False)
                            Order By m.Head
                            Select m

    If (ViewData("User") = False) Then
        Return View(articlesUserFalse)
    End If


    Return View(articlesUserTrue)
End Function
```

пример страницы :

```
@For Each item In Model
    @<p>
        @Html.ActionLink("" + item.Head + "", "About", New With {.id = item.Id})
    </p>
Next
```

в обоих случаях получаю контекст полностью , с учётом .Text - может весить много , что не нужно .

Вопрос : как , правильно получить только .Head и .Id записи в запросах , 
и с помощью чего лучше - LINQ или лямбда-выражений .
Если можно - примеры для этого случая в обоих вариантах .
Спасибо ...

Пока удалось решить вопрос только так , по новой пересобрав данные :

```
 Dim List As New List(Of AboutArticle)
 For Each x As AboutArticle In articlesUserFalse
     List.Add(New AboutArticle With {.Id = x.Id, .Head = x.Head})
 Next
```

В итоге получилось взять нужные данные из таблицы вот так

```
Dim HeadArticles = From m In context.AboutArticles
                           Order By m.Head
                           Select m.Head, m.Id, m.Right  
//или так   
Dim HeadArticles = context.AboutArticles.OrderBy(Function(m) m.Head).Select(Function(m) New With {.Head = m.Head, .Id = m.Id, .Right = m.Right}).ToList()
```

Привести их к нужному типу

```
Dim ListHead As New List(Of AboutArticle)
```

И передать на страницу полностью

```
For Each x In HeadArticles
    ListHead.Add(New AboutArticle With {.Id = x.Id, .Head = x.Head})
Next
Return View(ListHead)
```

или предварительно отсортировав

```
For Each x In HeadArticles
    If x.Right = False Then
          ListHead.Add(New AboutArticle With {.Id = x.Id, .Head = x.Head})
    End If
Next
Return View(ListHead)
```

Comment: если нужны не все данные то тогда я бы сделал как то так(пример на C#) `_context.AboutArticles.Select(x=> new AboutArticle{ Id = x.Id, Head = x.Head}).ToLIst();` в этом случае результат запроса будет содержать только те поля которые перечислены в конструкторе `new AboutArticle`

Comment: @Bald , спасибо , попробую , вечером отпишу .

Comment: @Bald, пишет следующее на такую `context.AboutArticles.Select(Function(x) New AboutArticle With {.Id = x.Id, .Head = x.Head}).ToList()` конструкцию   
`System.NotSupportedException: "В запросе LINQ to Entities нельзя конструировать тип сущности или сложный тип "MVC_With_Registration.AboutArticle"."
`